# password_verify_function in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

how can I create b) all users should have unique usernames and passwords. Password should be at least 8 characters long (enforced).

I know how to enforce 8 character in pl sql but how can I make sure user name and password is unique.

Comment: Did you look at the password function provided by Oracle. There a lot of new features in 12c.

Comment: I tried to run like Password_verify_function ora12c_verify_function but I am getting error like ora-07443 function "ora12c_verify_function" not found

Comment: Copy the function content from the .sql file, modify the way you want to implement the rules, compile it as your own user defined function. And use it to validate username and password.

Comment: could you please help me how to write the function.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides a function to be compiled under SYS for password verification and it's complexity. You will find it in `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlpwdmg.sql`.

With different releases, the function has been modified and new functions have been added. With `12c`, there are four more functions, `ora12c_verify_function` , `ora12c_strong_verify_function` and two helper functions `complexity_check` and `string_distance`.

Have a look at http://www.oradba.ch/2013/07/oracle-12c-new-password-verify-function/